# How to pass variables to functions called in spark_apply()?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I would like to be able to pass extra variables to functions that are called by spark_apply in sparklyr.

For example:

```
# setup
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master='local', packages=TRUE)
iris2 <- iris[,1:(ncol(iris) - 1)]
df1 <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris2, repartition=5, overwrite=T)

# This works fine
res <- spark_apply(df1, function(x) kmeans(x, 3)$centers)

# This does not
k <- 3
res <- spark_apply(df1, function(x) kmeans(x, k)$centers)
```

As an ugly workaround, I can do what I want by saving values into R packages, and then referencing them. i.e

```
> myPackage::k_equals_three == 3
[1] TRUE

# This also works
res <- spark_apply(df1, function(x) kmeans(x, myPackage::k_equals_three)$centers)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have spark set up to test, but can you just create a closure?

```
kmeanswithk <- function(k) {force(k); function(x) kmeans(x, k)$centers})
k <- 3
res <- spark_apply(df1, kmeanswithk(k))
```

Basically just create a function to return a function then use that.

Answer (score 2):

`spark_apply()` now has a `context` argument for you to pass additional objects/variables/etc to the environment.

```r
res <- spark_apply(df1, function(x, k) {
  kmeans(x, k)$cluster},
  context = {k <- 3})
```

or

```r
k <- 3
res <- spark_apply(df1, function(x, k) {
  kmeans(x, k)$cluster},
  context = {k})
```

The R documentation does not include any examples with the context argument, but you might learn more from reading the PR: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/pull/1107.